# react native ignores android navigation bar

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, expo

There is such a problem, the react native application does not take into account the Android navigation bar and goes under it. How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Could you please give more details on your problem? Start by explaining the environment and the steps to reproduce. If you need to add some screenshots, take a look at this post https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344851/how-do-you-add-a-screenshot-image-to-your-stack-overflow-post

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: I'm not a React programmer, but I still think that your question lacks a lot of information. The screenshot doesn't seem to provide much information to the question (I changed your screenshot so it is now seen on the question rather than being linked to it).